# Check if a shared workbook is already open by another user

Tags: excel, vb.net, shared

I am developing a program where some data is saved in an Excel file. It's a shared file, so everyone can use it. Before I open the file, I want to know if the file is already open for write by another user. At the moment I'm using the code below:

```
    Dim app As New Excel.Application
    Dim book As Excel.Workbook
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet

    If app.Workbooks.CanCheckOut("O:\T_Fiabilidade_QMM6\Recursos\Informáticos\SW Occupation rate\RPRS.xlsx") = True Then
        MsgBox("Available")
    Else
        MsgBox("Não disponível")
    End If
End Sub
```

But it always returns me the message "Não disponível" even if the file is closed. Can anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check `ReadOnly` property of the workbook,
if its true so somebody is using the workbook:

```
Dim app As New Application
Dim book As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet

Public Function IsWokBookInUse() As Boolean
    book = app.Workbooks.Open("")

    If book.ReadOnly = True Then
        MsgBox("the file is in use")
        ' optional: close workbook...'
        book.Close()
        app.Quit()
        Return True
    Else
        MsgBox("o.k")
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: glad i could help, please mark it as an answer by clicking the check mark icon.